# Uuable to use check box in if codition in wp8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, c#-5.0, onedrive

I am developing a demo app for Sky Drive in WP8. I get an error in an if condition:

```
if (client == null && cbSync.IsChecked==true )
{
    Auth();
    LiveOperationResult res = await client.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", fileName, e.ImageStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
}
else if((bool)cbSync.IsChecked==true)
{
    LiveOperationResult res= await client.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", fileName, e.ImageStream,OverwriteOption.Overwrite);

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: (client == null && cbSync.IsChecked==true ) is this condition is right..of client == null..it shouldn't be client !=null

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure, but it looks like this code is executed on a background thread, but UI objects have to be accessed from the UI thread.

I think the cleanest solution would be to convert the event into a `Task` using `TaskCompletionSource`. Then, in the code that starts the operation that eventually fires the event now, you would instead `await` the `Task` and then execute the code that's currently in the event handler.

That way, the code executes in the UI thread (so you can access UI objects there) and it's also better structured (all related code is in a single method).

If this won't work for you, you call `TaskFactory.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` from the UI thread, save the resulting `TaskFactory`, and then use it in the event handler to run the code on the UI thread.